# download data from Graphite using Python

Tags: graphite

I am a beginner so please be kind. I want to download CPU utilization rate from from some VMs installed on a server. The server has Graphite installed. I installed the Python graphite-api and I have the server connection details. How do I make the REST api call to start pulling the data ?

Comment: Here are python code to pull data, but its not using that AP, just urllibI: https://github.com/etsy/nagios_tools/blob/master/check_graphite_data

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) package:

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://your_graphite_host.com/render?target=app.numUsers&format=json', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.json()  # this will give your the JSON file with the data
```

Keep in mind that you will have to replace `app.numUsers` with the appropriate metric name. You can also request other formats and time ranges, see the [graphite-api docs](http://graphite-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html).

Comment: is there any other client?

Comment: yes, sure, you can use python urllib, or use any other programming language

Comment: i was looking for more better wrapper for graphite... `robust-graphite-client` might answer my need